# GIT: accidental inclusion of password..how do I fix it?

Tags: git, github

On a commit I accidentally included a password.  How do I remove this commit from the repository?

The push went to github so It's important that the commit be removed completely from the history.

Comment: Change your password.  Now.

Comment: password changed, it was for a local database file anyway.

Comment: Assume that everyone who can check out the repository already did.  On a public repo, that means you should assume everyone on the internet now knows that password and that username that goes with it.

Comment: Give me the address of the repo, I will try to fix it... xD just kidding :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Answer (score 3):

You should do as follow:

```sh
git log --oneline -S <COMMIT_SEARCH_PATTERN>

# Copy the commit hash

git rebase - i <COMMIT_HASH>~1

# Change the marker to **drop**
# Exit from the editor

git rebase --continue
git push --force
```

Answer (score -3):

To remove the password *for future* clones and fetches, I'd point you to `git rebase`, editing the commit and then doing a `git push --force`.

Of course - you have to change the password anyways.

Comment: The damage has been done. It doesn't matter if you remove it *now*, the problem is that the password was compromised in the first place. Anyone that retrieved the password before you overwrote the commit still has it.

Comment: I assumed removing the password from the repo would obviously be for cosmetics.